Can you use Yandex Cloud services, like the Yandex Search API, in the United States or are there sanctions against it?
I'm trying to sign up for the Yandex Search API.
When I'm creating a Service Account with them to sign up for the Search API, it's not letting my select the United States as a region.
I was going to sign up with a different region, but then it also asks for a Tax ID number.
Before I go any further, does anybody know if there are legal issues surrounding using the Yandex Search API in America?
Edit: Attached is a screenshot of the list of countries (after translating from Russian) that you can use to sign up. 

Do the unavailable regions match https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unfriendly_countries_list#List_of_countries_and_regions ?

No, you can sign up with United Kingdom, Norway, Switzerland, etc

ChatGPT is saying "The use of Yandex.Cloud services in the United States is not explicitly prohibited by U.S. sanctions.". But obviously I'm here to get better advice

Unless ChatGPT or other AI provides a source written by humans, I'd always assume they're just hallucinating.

I've also emailed Yandex Cloud and I'll update this post with their reply in a day or so

No
The co-owner of Yandex is sanctioned by the US under Executive Order 14024 of April 15, 2021 which in Section 2(b) prohibits:

the receipt of any contribution or provision of funds, goods, or services
from any such person.


I don't see him on the Yandex Wikipedia Page. It also looks like Yandex was sold earlier this year:
https://searchengineland.com/yandex-search-sale-437206
https://sifted.eu/articles/yandex-russia-google-europe

@stevealereza Government takes time.

It is the company's right to not do Business in the US
If the company does not want to do business in the USA, they can not do business there. That is their right to choose contracts. If you claim to be in another country, that would be fraud.
Whatever the reason is, we don't know or need to know. It is like Geoblocking Europe. They don't want to do business with you, and you can't force them. In effect, they don't block you based on your nationality but because of the country you are doing your main business in. The nationality of a person could be a protected class, but works in Country X is not a protected characteristic.
Yandex isn't in any US Jurisdiction to be sued
If you'd try to sue for access, you can not do that in the USA, as Yandex has no business inside the US, no representative and by doing no business in the US, did not avail itself to any US court. As such, you'd need to sue in Russia.
